# When i am deploying my angular app in tomcat it creates two foldername in the url leads to 404 error

Tags: angular, web, tomcat, deployment, web-deployment

When i am deploying my angular app in tomcat it creates two filename in the url leads to 404 error.I have used the command ng build --base-href=usersfront. Please help me with the issue.[image]

Comment: Try with this url http://localhost:8080/userfront/index.html

Comment: it throws this error in console

Comment: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'usersfront' @SantoshShinde

Comment: what is path of ```index.html``` inside deployed directory structure.

Comment: i am adding the index.html file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow bellow steps

1. `ng build --base-href=/userfront/`
2. After successfully build the project
3. Create `userfront` folder inside tomcat `web-apps` and copy all files(html, css and js) from `dist` folder to `userfront` folder.
4. And Try with this url  [http://localhost:8080/userfront/index.html](https://localhost:8080/userfront/index.html)

Comment: Same issue occurs

Comment: No changes @Santosh Shinde